# MSBuild doesn't continue on errors over dependencies

Tags: visual-c++, msbuild, visual-studio-2015

I have two visual studio projects:

- Project A,
- Project B having a file which doesn't compile.

I have a visual studio solution which contains those two projects. I set a project dependency to have A that depends on B. The build order would be B, A.

When visual studio IDE builds the solution, the behaviour is:

1. Project B starts to compile and fails showing errors,
2. Project A starts to compile.

When msbuild builds the solution, it compiles project B, shows the errors and doesn't continue by compiling project A. I'm using the following command line to build the solution:

```
msbuild my.sln /target:Build /property:Configuration=Debug /property:Platform=x64
```

Why msbuild and visual studio IDE don't have the same behaviour by default? 
Is there a simple way to have msbuild continuing on errors without defining a msbuild project file?

(I'm using visual studio 2015 and simple C++ projects)

Comment: Try: msbuild my.sln /target:Build /property:Configuration=Debug;Platform=x64;ContinueOnError=true

Comment: This command line doesn't help. I've tried to add also the property StopOnFirstFailure=false without any success...

Comment: Strange : [MSBuild documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff960151%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)